# PHP Class Inheritance - Out of Memory

Tags: php, class, oop

I see everywhere that you cannot extend multiple classes...i.e.

```
Class Foo{
    //DO FOO STUFF HERE
}

Class Bar{
    //DO BAR STUFF HERE
}

Class FooBar extends Foo,Bar{
    //DO FOOBAR STUFF HERE
}
```

That makes sense, but what about:

```
Class Foo{
    //DO FOO STUFF HERE
}

Class Bar extends Foo{
    //DO BAR STUFF HERE
}

Class FooBar extends Foo{
    //DO FOOBAR STUFF HERE
}
```

For example, can you have multiple child classes extend the same parent? When I try this, I get an out of memory error, and I tried increasing the memory limit to 512MB but I still get out of memory errors...

What is a way to check memory usage, I mean these are very basic classes, i.e. one public variable, and the Bar class sets the value for the variable in the Foo class...It's a constant thing, but if I wait 15-20 minutes and try again, it is fine. My issue is, this server has 32GB of Ram, and I have even tried the stupid setting memory to 1024M as well.

[Edit Code:]

```
Class CORE{
    public $load;
    public $data;
    public $models;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load=New Loader;
        $this->data=New Database;
        $this->data->db=New PDO(DSN);
    }
    public function __dev_email($subject, $message){
        $to="dev@mydomain.com";
        $headers="From: \"Error Checking\" <dev@mydomain.com>";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
class Loader extends CORE{
    public function model($name){
        if (file_exists("/var/www/models/".$name.".php")){
            require_once("/var/www/models/".$name.".php");
            $models[$name]=New $name;
        }
    }
}
class Error extends CORE{
    $this->__dev_email("Bad Database Connection", "Invalid Connection Attempt was made. Please check the configuration.");
}
```

Keep in mind this is not all of the code, there is an Autoloader, and several different files, but this is a basic version, and I just checked, I am still getting out of memory errors from this.

Comment: Sure, you can extend a class that extends.  What problems you are encountering is something in your `//DO STUFF HERE` implementations.  Like, for example, if you were to instantiate an instance of an object in its own constructor leading to an infinite chain of instantiations...

Comment: yes, it's valid. you're basically just branching the family tree. Such inheritance isn't a simple sizeof(Foobar) + sizeof(Foo). The whole point of inheritance is that code is reused. Technically/vaguely, sizeof(Foobar) will be `sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(any changes made in Foobar that aren't in Foo)`

Comment: In your second example, surely you mean `FooBar extends Bar`?

Comment: Let me post some code...one sec

Comment: Could it be that I am calling the CORE class, and then the autoloader is calling the Error class which is also calling the CORE class again? I will feel awefully stupid if that is the cause...

Comment: I am fairly sure that you cannot do this in PHP: `public $load=New Loader();`

Comment: sorry, thanks for pointing that out.you can't.

Comment: Constructors are inherited too .. when you are initializing `Loader` instance, the `CORE` constructor is called .. which tries to initialize new `Loader`. Basically: you have endless loop. Also, i really hope that this is not some "mvc framework". We have had 4 such posts in past hour already.

Comment: I did not realize that constructors were inherited.

Comment: This is not an MVC, this is a personal project to help me get more acquanted with Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: @JustinE You shouldn't use inheritance here. Instead consider composition, perhaps by dependency injection.

Comment: I have never even heard of this, but research proves you to be correct @WaleedKhan thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are initializing CORE, it creates a new instance of Loader which extends CORE. This causes the CORE constructor to be called again, which in turn creates another Loader meaning it continues forever leading to the out of memory errors.

One way which might work is passing the CORE to the Loader class on initialization as shown below.

```
Class CORE{
    public $load;
    public $data;
    public $models;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load=New Loader($this);
        $this->data=New Database;
        $this->data->db=New PDO(DSN);
    }
    public function __dev_email($subject, $message){
        $to="dev@mydomain.com";
        $headers="From: \"Error Checking\" <dev@mydomain.com>";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
class Loader{
    private $core;

    public function __construct($core){
        $this->core = $core;
    }

    public function model($name){
        if (file_exists("/var/www/models/".$name.".php")){
            require_once("/var/www/models/".$name.".php");
            $this->core->models[$name]=New $name;
        }
    }
}
class Error extends CORE{
    $this->__dev_email("Bad Database Connection", "Invalid Connection Attempt was made. Please check the configuration.");
}
```